# JNI build C file (Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64)

Tags: macos, build, java-native-interface, linker-errors, x86-64

I'm trying to build a .c file on OSX but I keep getting:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64
```

```
#include "Test.h"  

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Test_test
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass cls, jbyteArray s, jlong ss, jbyteArray sss, jlong ssss, jbyteArray sssss, jlong ssssss) {

  /*printf("Hello World!\n");*/
  return 1;
}
```

Built with:

```
clang++ -o test -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/include  -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin Test.cpp

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there something I need to install?

Answer (score 1):

`clang++ -o test Test.cpp` is trying to compile *and link* to produce a runnable executable.  You didn't define `main()`, so of course this fails when it tries to link the CRT code (which calls the user-supplied `main()`.)

Perhaps you meant to use `clang++ -fPIC -shared -o libtest.so Test.cpp -I...`   (keeping all the other options the same), to make a shared library like JNI needs.  Or `.dylib` or `.jnilib`, whatever libraries are normally called on your platform.

If you're following a tutorial that didn't tell you how to compile your code, it's probably not a very good tutorial and you should find better documentation.

Comment: Probably not the right answer, as a JNI module is a shared object and you'd be producing a straight object file.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: ah right, that makes sense.  `-fPIC -shared` should be about right, IIRC.

Comment: the OP says OSX so it should probably be `.dylib` or `.jnilib` (and I'd give the file a `lib` prefix and isn't the command now missing the `-o`?)

Comment: @user2543253: thanks.  This was a pretty lazy answer; I probably should have just posted a comment since I didn't want to put in the effort to write a good answer. >.<